# How to align text in center from all dimensions for textview?

Tags: android, android-layout

i am using `relative layout` and I have two `textviews` with colored back-grounds, I want to position the text in `center` from all sides so which attributes should I use?

Comment: post your xml if you have sample output post it also

Answer (score 0):

First example:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="A"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="B"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Second Example with constraint:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="A" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="B" />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```